# Windows Live ID/Live connect, how to get current logged in user's email

Tags: windows-live-id, live-connect-sdk

First, I am using Live connect, as documents says live id will be obsolete

When a user log in my site with Live connect, I want to get the email address which he/she input when he log in.

I can not find a way to get such information, it's so weird.

From /me URL, i can get user's name, id, local and so on, but can not get email address.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Success by add scope wl.emails